# Langevin equation and convergence to stationary solutions. Free energy. SDE. FPE.

Tags: convergence-divergence, partial-differential-equations, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-differential-equations, stationary-processes

Let $f\geq 0$ be Lipschtiz. The overdamped Langevin equation

\begin{equation}\label{eq overdamped Langevin SDE}
     dX=-\nabla f(X)dt+\sqrt{2} dW_t
 \end{equation}
with Kolmogorov forward equation
\begin{equation}
   ~~~~~~~~~~~~  \partial_t \rho = \text{div} (\rho \nabla f)+\Delta \rho \tag 1
 \end{equation}
has associated free energy
\begin{equation}
     F(\rho)=\int f \rho + \int \rho \log \rho.
\end{equation}

It is easy to see that \begin{equation}
\rho^\infty(x) := \frac{e^{-f(x)}}{\int e^{-f(x)}dx},
\end{equation}

is a stationary distribution of the overdamped dynamics, since

\begin{align*}
\int e^{-f(x)}dx  \big( \text{div}(\rho^\infty \nabla f )+ \Delta \rho^\infty \big) &=    \text{div}(e^{-f} \nabla f)+  \text{div}\nabla e^{-f}   
    \\
    &=  \text{div} (e^{-f} \nabla f)+  \text{div}(- \nabla f e^{-f}) = 0
\end{align*}

My question is

> Consider $(1)$, coupled with the initial condition that
> $\rho(0,x)=\rho_0(x)$. Under what conditions on the initial
> distribution $\rho_0$ and on the function $f$ do we need for the
> solution $\rho$ to actually converge (in some norm like $L^1, L^2$ or
> $W_2$ ) to the stationary distribution $\rho^\infty$? Moreover it is
> obvious that $\rho^\infty$ is a minimiser of the free energy $F$?

---

EDIT:

1. Here we are considering dynamics in $\mathbb{R}^d$, where $W_t$ is a d-dimensional Brownian motion and $W_2$ is the 2-Wasserstein norm.
2. The link [here](https://www.cedricvillani.org/sites/dev/files/old_images/2012/07/024.CMcV_.pdf) kind of answers my question.

Comment: Remind me, if you don’t mind, what is the $W_2$ norm again?

Comment: @NapD.Lover Ill edit the question.

Comment: Sorry all, this kind of answers things : https://www.cedricvillani.org/sites/dev/files/old_images/2012/07/024.CMcV_.pdf

Comment: Based off your second edit: Might I suggest summarizing your findings, then, into an answer to your own question. This is certainly encouraged and then would give anyone searching this a nice summary before diving deeper.

Comment: I feel like there is a pretty big difference bewteen the paper you shared and the OP. In (1.1) of the paper they have a deterministic equation (in terms of a probability measure sure but still deterministic) but yours has a $W_t$ term in it. Unless (1.1) can be written in a form that's more similar to the OP that i'm not aware of.